# How to filter based on multiple column values from another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a data frame that I am trying to filter based on 2 ID columns from the first data frame. Here's data frame 1:

| id_1 | id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

And data frame 2:

| id_1 | id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 2 |

If I do something like...

```
df2_filtered <- df2 %>%
filter(id_1 %in% df1$id_1 &
        id_2 %in% df1$id_2)
```

Then I get back the entirety of df2, which is not what I want. Even though "A" is in id_1 of df1, and "2" is in id_2 of df1, there is no row that has both. How do I fix it so that I only get back

| id_1 | id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::inner_join`:

```
inner_join(data1, data2)

# Joining, by = c("id_1", "id_2")
# id_1 id_2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
```

Comment: This does the trick. Although I have to put an extra select statement afterwards to trim out the columns I don't want, that's easy enough.

Comment: If you are trying to filter rows that are NOT included in data2, the anti_join function works for that. This post helped answer my problem which was the opposite of this. Just posting this in case someone has the same question as I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't bound to a `dplyr` solution, then `data.table` has a nice option:

```
library(data.table)
df1 = as.data.table(df1)
df2 = as.data.table(df2)
fintersect(df1, df2)
```

```
   id_1 id_2
1:    A    1
2:    B    2
```